# Максимальное число линий, равноудалённых от трёх точек

Tags: геометрия

Сколько линий можно провести одной плоскости так, чтобы все они находились на одинаковом расстоянии от трёх неколлинеарных точек? Докажите ваш ответ.

*Дополнение*. Линия — это прямая. Все линии должны находиться на одинаковом расстоянии именно от точек.

Comment: @Типичный программист, Это вопрос на форум [Математика](http://math.hashcode.ru/).

Comment: Поясните условие пожалуйста.
1. Что такое линия? Прямая или кривая?
2. Что от чего на одинаковом расстоянии? Линия от всех 3-х точек? Или все линии от каждой из точек?

Comment: @Типичный программист, почему вы пропустили одну пятницу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Три. Так как каждая такая линия (g) должна быть параллельна одной из сторон (а) и пересекать две остальные (б и в). Первое, очевидно, так как вершины стороны (а) равноудалены от линии, т.е. прямая, содержащая (а) параллельна (g).
А второе - потому что, если прямая будет проходить за пределами треугольника, то третья вершина и (g) буду по разные стороны от прямой (а), а значит расстояние от третьей вершины до (g) будет больше, чем расстояние прямой (а) от (g).

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем согласен с ответом [[@AlexzundeR](/users/8475/alexzunder)](/users/8475/alexzunder). Здесь идёт речь о том, что точки должны быть равноудалены от линии, а не от какой-то точки.

Кратчайшее расстояние от линии (я так понимаю, в задаче имеется ввиду прямая) является перпендикуляр, опущенный с точки до прямой. Порисовав пару минут на листочке можно прийти к нехитрому выводу, что такими линиями должны быть средние линии треугольника, а значит таких линий может быть только **три**

Answer (score 1):

Косяк ) Согласен, 3 штуки, параллельно каждой стороне треугольника на расстоянии половины высоты к этой стороне )

Answer (score 1):

Все очень просто. Три линии, как и три точки. Делается это так: обозначим точки A,B,C. Выбераем любые две(например, А и В) и проводим линию между ними. Искомая будет параллельна данной. После этого проводим AC(или BC), определяем середину(думаю, с помощью линейки без делений и циркуля все справятся) и через эту точку проводим прямую параллельную AB. Всего получится 6 прямых, но 3 наложатся на три другие. Это уровень региональной олимпиады для восьмиклассников, не более того.

Comment: тоже так думаю

Answer (score 1):

Три.
Каждая проводится так: сначала проводится линия через две из них, к ней проводится перпендикуляр из третей точки, заданая линия проходит паралельно первой через средину перпендикуляра. Построение такое уникально для каждой комбинации точек, а комбинаций будет всего три.

Comment: согласен с этим

Answer (score 1):

Если плоскость не ограничена условием, то на равноудаленном от всех трех точек расстоянии в бесконечность, можно провести бесконечное число линий.

Answer (score 1):

три, конечно. Они неколлинеарны => есть треугольник. Если мы проведем линию так, что все три точки лежат по одну сторону от нее, то очевидно, что она нам не подходит(если бы все точки лежали на расстоянии s от нее, то они бы лежали на параллельной прямой на расстоянии s от нашей). Значит, с одной стороны от такой линии лежит одна точка, а с другой - две. Мы всегда можем провести такую прямую, чтобы расстояние было одинаково. В итоге, три.

Answer (score 0):

Бесконечное множество, так как существует единственная точка равноудаленная от 3-х неколлинеарных точек в двумерном пространстве - это центр описанной вокруг треугольника, образованного этими точками окружности. А через одну точку в двумерном пространстве можно провести бесконечное количество прямых.

Comment: По-моему вы путаете определение расстояния от точки до прямой ;)

Answer (score 0):

Что за бред, что еще за неколлинеарные точки?)
По идее, о да, и это правда, через любые две точки можно провести прямую,
но тут, скорее, подразумевается взаимная неколлинеарность всех 3х точек - 
тогда можем построить плоскость! и только одну!)
Если по существу, то таких прямых бесконечно много - абстрактно геометрически!)
Ну если пойти от простого - взять 2е точки на прямой и построить от нее серединный перпендикуляр, на нем поставить точку (без извращений). Затем также провести серединные перпендикуляры для двух других пар точек, их точка пересечения - наша точка,
через кот-ую мы можем провести бесконечно много таких прямых.
Док-во: см. св-вы треуг-ка (внимательно!)